# How to refresh GridView after it is scrolled programmatically?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll-offset

I have a `GridView` nested into the following way:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    <LinearLayout 
        <com.j4nos.moviebuffs10.CustomGridView
```

`GridView` is scrolled programmatically, like: `gridview.scrollBy(0, dy);` The problem is that content is moving out from the view, but new items are not sliding inside. Why? Do I need to refresh? How often? Scroll method is called quite frequently.

Answer (score 1):

To Update and Refresh the GridView , you need to make changes in GridView Adapter:

```
 adapter.notifyDataChanged();
 gridView.invalidateViews();
 gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: implemented, but unfortunatelly, content still not appears, but app get really slow